# Parsing "following as it did close on the great Pan-Anglican Congress"

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, parsing

> The fifth Lambeth Conference, **following as it did close on the great Pan-Anglican Congress**, is remarkable mainly as a proof of the growth of the influence and many-sided activity of the Anglican Church, and as a conspicuous manifestation of her characteristic principles.

In the sentence above, does the bold part of sentence equal "which is following as it did close on the great Pan-Anglican Congress" or "which follows as it did close on the great Pan-Anglican Congress"?

Plus, in the bold part of sentence, what is part of speech of the word "as"? Is it a conjunction? I mean, the "as" in the sentence above equals *when*/*while*, right?

Comment: And the "following" here is an adjective,right?

Answer (score 1):

> The fifth lambeth conference,FOLLOWING AS IT DID CLOSE ON THE GREAT
>   PAN-ANGLICAN CONGRESS,is remarkable mainly as a proof of the growth of
>   the influence and many-sided activity of the anglican church,and as a
>   conspicious manifestation of her characteristic principles

The phrase you have placed in uppercase modifies **conference**.

...following {as it did} close on the great pan-anglican conference

"To follow close (up)on" something means to happen soon after it.

"as it did" is parenthetical. In the manner that it did. "Like" would be a closer paraphrase for "as" than "when" or "while".

**The orangutan, making its nest, as it does, high up in the trees, spends the night in safety far from predators prowling below.**

Comment: One simply has to love your example sentence!